# Return completed map before rendering it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an a component that handles a list, and has some internal logic to determine if it should render as a ul, or as a div. If the list is empty, it renders as a `div`, and if the list has elements, it renders as a `ul`.

I'm making an API call to get the potential list of elements. When I loop through,

```
<ParentUlOrDiv>
  {data.map(el => {
    <div>test</div>
  })}
  <div>final row</div>
</ParentUlOrDiv>
```

The parent doesn't know the amount of elements it will have to render, so it plugs them all into one `li`, meaning that I'll get all sorts of visual misbehavior.

How can I return the complete, mapped list from `data` and pass that that to the `ParentUlOrDiv` as a child (as then it'd know the amount of elements it needs to render)?

If I just hardcode two `div`s instead of the map, I'm rendering correctly. But with a map, I get issues.

Comment: You could count the number of children from the deeper component right? NOt sure what your asking

Comment: How to render only when completed array from the map!

Comment: You currently have no return value in your `map()` callback. Change `el => { <div>test</div> }` into `el => (<div>test</test>)` for an implicit return (notice the curly bracket change), or add an explicit `return` before `<div>test</div>`. See: [Arrow function expressions: Function body - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being because of a mixture of dynamic / static content within the parent. It has to all be dynamic, coming from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use `props.children.length` to choose between an `ul` or the `div`.

---

Example were the children are wrapped in a `ul` and `li` if there are more then 1. Otherwise, it's just rendered in a `div`

```js
const ParentUlOrDiv = (props) => {
  console.log('ParentUlOrDiv got', props.children.length, 'children');
  
  const WrapElement = props.children.length > 1 ? 'ul' : 'div';
  
  const values = props.children.length > 1 ? props.children.map(c => <li>{c}</li>) : props.children;
  
  return <WrapElement>{values}</WrapElement>;
}

const Example = () => {
    
    const data = [
      'Foo', 'Bar'
    ]

    return (
        <ParentUlOrDiv>
            {data.map(d => <em>{d}</em>)}
        </ParentUlOrDiv>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: The decision between the div / ul happens in the parent component that comes from a component library, so for me I just need to return a completed list from map, and pass that as the child to this component

Comment: Huh, you're already doning that in the code in your question. NOt sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: I'm not as the ParentUlOrDiv is rendered before the array is returned from the data.map

Comment: Just adding two divs instead of a map renders it correctly, so the issue is that the map happens after render